# Android Game Dev - NullPointerException after declaring new object (constructor not doing what I want it to do)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, libgdx

I'm currently learning game programming using a framework called libgdx. It allows users to make programs that can easily run on both a Java virtual machine on the desktop and an Android mobile phone. I am trying to make a basic program that will display a character on screen and allow me to move it back and forth with the keyboard. I have created 3 classes - one called `Assets`, which loads files into the memory and converts them into Textures and Animations, one called `InputHandler`, which responds to key input by changing animations, direction of movement etc., and one called `FightView`, which is essentially where all the rendering gets done. The `InputHandler` is called from the `FightView` class with the typical command `input = new InputHandler(anim, frame);`. The constructor for `InputHandler` looks like this:

```
public InputHandler(Animation animation, TextureRegion region){

    Assets.load();  //loads textures from files into memory and creates animations from them
    animation = Assets.playStance;  //set initial animation to be used
    region = animation.getKeyFrame(0, true);    //make TextureRegion equal to first frame in animation

}
```

Now, what I want to happen is simply that the Animation and TextureRegion passed into the constructor are set to the values quoted above, so that, for example, if I was to mention `region` in the `FightView` class after `input` had been declared, it would be set as `animation.getKeyFrame(0, true);`. From my limited experience of Java this is what I believe should happen, but I get a NullPointerException at compile time pointing to the second line in the code below:

```
    input = new InputHandler(anim, frame);
    x = centreX - (frame.getRegionWidth() / 2);
```

Clearly, `frame` is still null, even after being passed through the constructor, which (as can be see in the third line in the constructor) should assign to it a value. Note that before being passed into the constructor they both are actually null - I am trying to create a class that will give the fields data without needing to do so in the `FightView` class.

Any help appreciated. This could be the wrong way to go about this - what I am trying to do is create an object that, upon initialisation, will load the `Animation` and `TextureRegion`s with data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is due to a misunderstanding of a basic Java concept.  Java passes parameters by value, not reference.  What you have written will never work as you expect.

First, I recommend you perhaps tackle a simpler problem or take a side trip to reinforce some of the basic Java concepts and object concepts.

Second, here's a brief answer to achieve what you desire.

Add members to the InputHandler class to hold an Animation and a TextureRegion.  In the constructor (which would take no parameters) you would assign the values like you have done except you would assign them to the member variables.

```
class InputHandler {

    public Animation animation;
    public TextureRegion region;

    public InputHandler() {

        Assets.load();  //loads textures from files into memory and creates animations from them
        animation = Assets.playStance;  //set initial animation to be used
        region = animation.getKeyFrame(0, true);    //make TextureRegion equal to first frame in animation

    }
}
```

After constructing the InputHandler you could reference it's members (frame in this case) and see your correct values.

```
input = new InputHandler();
x = centreX - (input.frame.getRegionWidth() / 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did what you said and now the code looks like this: 
      input = new InputHandler();
  frame = input.frame;
  x = centreX - (frame.getRegionWidth() / 2);
I also have a method in InputHandler called update() that changes the animations etc. when a button is pressed. Will I need to write the `frame = input.frame` line after I call that method in order to make those changes?